# 'horizontal(layoutSize:subitem:count:)' was deprecated in iOS 16.0

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uikit, uicollectionviewcompositionallayout

Im using the UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout to lay my collection view items side by side for landscape and single tile on normal mood. Thus, I use NSCollectionLayoutGroups to achieve this objective. I get the mentioned error when I define my group. My code as bellow.

```
private func layout() -> UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout {
    
    let layout = UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout { sectionIndex, environment -> NSCollectionLayoutSection? in
        
        let itemSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize (
            widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(0.2),
            heightDimension: .estimated(400)
        )
        let item = NSCollectionLayoutItem(layoutSize: itemSize)
        
        let groupSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize (
            widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(1.0),
            heightDimension: .estimated(400)
        )
        
        let columns = (environment.container.contentSize.width > 500 && self.toggleSwitch.isOn) ? 2 : 1
        
       //MARK: Error horizontal(layoutSize:subitem:count:)' was deprecated in iOS 16.0
        let group = NSCollectionLayoutGroup.horizontal(layoutSize: groupSize, subitem: item, count: columns)
        
        group.interItemSpacing = .fixed(20)
        
        if columns > 1 {
            group.contentInsets.leading = 20
            group.contentInsets.trailing = 20
        }
        
        let section = NSCollectionLayoutSection(group: group)
        section.interGroupSpacing = 20
        section.contentInsets.top = 20
        
        return section
    }
    
    let config = UICollectionViewCompositionalLayoutConfiguration()
    config.interSectionSpacing = 50
    layout.configuration = config
    
    return layout
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's been replaced with `horizontal(layoutSize:repeatingSubitem:count:)` instead as documented on [Apple's developer site](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/nscollectionlayoutgroup/3975795-horizontal). This is how you would update your code:

```
let group = NSCollectionLayoutGroup.horizontal(layoutSize: groupSize, repeatingSubitem: item, count: columns)
```